# What are "df", "t", and "p" in these sharpe ratio related estimates?

Tags: statistics, risk-management, sharpe-ratio

I am looking at some sharpe ratio related estimates and have not seen Sharpe stats broken down this way before.  I don't know what is meant by df, t, and p.  Can someone explain that to me?  Thank you!

[image: Here is the picture]

Comment: Some documentaion of these stats appears here: https://www.collective2.com/c2StatsGuide.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The Sharpe Ratio and the T-Statistic for the hypothesis that returns are equal to the risk free rate, are closely related (occasionally some people mistakenly think they are the same).

In fact: "The t-statistic will equal the Sharpe Ratio times the square root of N (the number of returns used for the calculation)." [1](https://web.stanford.edu/~wfsharpe/art/sr/sr.htm)

So it makes sense to show both. Then, by looking up the T-statistic t in a Student-t table with the right degrees of freedom you can come up with p the probability in a one-tailed test under the null. The df (degrees of freedom) is simply the number of (monthly) returns.

Comment: Thank you. Can't upvote you because I just signed up but I appreciate your answer. I saw this on Collective 2 and appreciate the link.